# How to type greek in LaTeX environment?

Tags: fonts, languages, greek

I'm Greek. I want to be able to type various sentences and phrases in greek in TexMaker preferably. Is there a way to do so, by installing additional packages, or configuring those already installed etc?

I had these installed

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LGR, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textgreek}
```

But i get many errors with the greek letters, such as "textomicron unavailable in encoding T1. See the LaTeX manual..". I've tried various things to no avail. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `babel`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

This is in English, but we also have
\textgreek{μια φράση στα ελληνικά}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: or switch them round if Greek is the main language. `\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}`

Comment: I thank you very much indeed (Ευχαριστώ πολύ).

Comment: @RestlessC0bra I trusted Google Translate for the Greek phrase, as I know nothing of the language, beyond the alphabet. `;-)`

Comment: @SamY. No. Are you sure you saved the file as UTF-8?

Comment: @egreg What do you mean by save as UTF-8?  I just saved it like I do all my other LaTex documents and then compiled...?

Comment: @egreg I just posted my question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/620446/the-greek-letters-in-my-document-are-appearing-as-semicolons-why)

Comment: For me the order of languages in `\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}` was critical. If I write `\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}` I get the whole text in Greek characters. ´:-\

Comment: @loved.by.Jesus That's right: the last language is the default one for the document. Unless you prefix the main language you want with `main=`