# Unable to write greek with package pdfx

Tags: greek, pdf-a, pdfx

I want to use package `pdfx` in order to produce a PDF-A document, but as soon as I load the package I can't write greek anymore because I'm getting the following error:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character μ (U+03BC)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

Here is my MWE (borrowed from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/348054/28685)):

```
\documentclass{article}

%\let\realnoboundary\noboundary \usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx} \let\noboundary\realnoboundary

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

This is in English, but we also have \textgreek{μια φράση στα ελληνικά}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't get the problem. If I remove the `%` the code still works fine, even with pdfx loaded.

Comment: I get the error. The problem is that pdfx messes up the latex inputenc/fontenc system and so lgrenc.dfu is not loaded. You can move babel before pdfx, then it works again. But I suggest also a bug report to the maintainer.

Comment: I reported the bug, the problem is being solved, the package should be updated in a couple of weeks.