# The Greek letters in my document are appearing as semicolons. Why?

Tags: greek, texshop

Using a [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348052/how-to-type-greek-in-latex-environment/348054?noredirect=1#comment1549193_348054) provided by @egreg, I am experiencing some strange output when using the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

This is in English, but we also have
\textgreek{μια φράση στα ελληνικά}

\end{document}
```

When I compile, the output I get has semicolons in the place of the Greek letters:

[image]

My log file:

[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please, show also the contents of the log file.

Comment: I can’t duplicate your problem, but [here is another solution that might work for you,.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/603418/switching-fonts-automatically-based-on-script-not-just-mixing-alphabets-in-the) It also lets you leave out `\textgreek`.

Comment: What happens if you add `% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode` at the very beginning of the file, save and rerun LaTeX?

Comment: @egreg I'm a little confused...I can't just write `TEX encoding=UTF-8 Unicode` in my preamble, can I?

Comment: Don't forget the  leading `%`

Comment: @egreg It worked! I have no idea why it worked, or how you knew to do this (!?!?!), but it worked!  (If you want to write this up as an answer, I will accept it.)

Comment: @SamY. I saw “TeXShop” and the encoding quirk came to my mind. I've set the default encoding to UTF-8 several years ago, although I rarely use the program. I prefer to use Aquamacs as editor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For strange reasons, TeXShop by default saves files in ISO-Latin-9 encoding. Indeed, if I run the following file

```
% !TEX encoding = IsoLatin9

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

This is in English, but we also have
\textgreek{μια φράση στα ελληνικά}

\end{document}
```

I get the semicolons.

Change the first line to

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
```

and the problem will disappear.

Also go to the preferences and change the default encoding:

[image]

The relevant drop-down menu is under “Encoding”. This will save all files in UTF-8.

Comment: It’s an extremely poor choice for TexShop to save in a format other than the default that LaTeX expects, but even worse to lose data when it saves and not even warn the user about it.